# How can I solve $x^2+2xy+y^2+3x-3y-18=0$

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, multivariable-calculus, quadratics

$$x^2+2xy+y^2+3x-3y-18=0$$

I don't know how to solve it.

Comment: what kind of variables are $$X,x,y$$?

Comment: Use $x^2+2xy+y^2=(x+y)^2$

Comment: There are infinitely many pairs of solutions

Comment: x,y are real numbers

Comment: I did a very similar one about 15 minutes ago. Yours is a little easier, still a parabola    http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2119461/canonic-form-of-a-conic/2119687#2119687

Comment: What do you mean by "solve" ? There infinitely many $(x,y)$ that satisfy the equation $(3,-3),(-6,0), (0,6)$... To be noticed: if $(x,y)$ is solution, $(y,-x)$ is solution.

Answer (score 4):

When a general conic equation

$$ Ax^2+Bxy+Cy^2+Dx +Ey +F=0$$

has $B\ne0$ and $A=C$ then rotating it $45^\circ$ will eliminate the $xy$ term.

This will be accomplished by the substitution

\begin{eqnarray}
x&=&\frac{X-Y}{\sqrt{2}}\\
y&=&\frac{(X+Y)}{\sqrt{2}}
\end{eqnarray}

\begin{equation}
x^2+2xy+y^2+3x-3y-18=0
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\frac{(X-Y)^2}{2}+(X-Y)(X+Y)+\frac{(X+Y)^2}{2}+\frac{3}{\sqrt{2}}(X-Y)-\frac{3}{\sqrt{2}}(X+Y)-18=0
\end{equation}

$$X^2=\frac{3}{\sqrt{2}}Y+18$$
So it is the equation of a parabola rotated $45^\circ$ about the origin.

[image: Parabola rotated 45 degrees]

Comment: Question, is the parabola rotated about the origin or rotated about something else?

Comment: Yes, about the origin.

Comment: Hi,could you please tell me what background knowledge is required to solve it?I am lost on how did you solve it.

@JohnWaylandBales

Comment: Here is a link to an explanation of the method used: https://www.algebra.com/algebra/homework/Trigonometry-basics/Trigonometry-basics.faq.question.860401.html

Answer (score 1):

If you want to solve with respect to $x$ that write the equation as:
$$
x^2+x(2y+3)+y^2-3y-18=0
$$
that use the quadratic formula
$$
x=\frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}
$$
with
$$
a=1 \qquad b=2y+3 \qquad c=y^2-3y-18
$$

If you want to solve with respect to $y$ do the same ordering the equation in $y$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint

$$
 \color{red}{x^2}+\color{red}{2x}y+y^2+\color{red}{3x}-3y+18=\color{red}{\left(x+y+\frac{3}{2}\right)^2-3y-y^2-\frac{9}{4}}+y^2-3y-18
$$

Find a second square end solve the equation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the transformation
 x=1/√2(a+b)
y=1/√2(-a+b)